# Fatal exception while starting activity using intent (null pointer exception)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

The following piece of code is throwing a null pointer exception in my application.Im trying to invoke an activity through an intent, (some background info on this is that the activity being opened is triggered through the click of a button, thus I have called the startActivity() function in the button's onclickListener itself.

Here's the code:

```
public class CategoryButtonOnClickListener extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final int position;
    public CategoriesPage categoriesPage;
    Context context;

    public CategoryButtonOnClickListener(int position, Context contextPassed) {
        this.position = position;
        this.context  = contextPassed;
        categoriesPage = new CategoriesPage();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        callCategoryList(this.position);
    }

    public void callCategoryList(int position) {
        String[] categories = categoriesPage.getCategories();
        Intent categoriesList = new Intent(this.context,BooksWithCategories.class);
        //I tried commenting this code to fix it as seen from another post, didnt work
        //categoriesList.putExtra("Category:",categories[position]);
        startActivity(categoriesList);
        //Toast.makeText(context,categories[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

The error thrown is as follows:

```
 1-17 23:27:15.076    2614-2614/com.dogra.booker E/AndroidRuntime﹕    FATAL    EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dogra.booker, PID: 2614
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
        at com.dogra.booker.UI.Model.CategoryButtonOnClickListener.callCategoryList(CategoryButtonOnClickListener.java:36)
        at com.dogra.booker.UI.Model.CategoryButtonOnClickListener.onClick(CategoryButtonOnClickListener.java:29)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Any suggestions on what could be the problem are appreciated.

Comment: Do you use `startActivity()` to start the strangely named `CategoryButtonOnClickListener` Activity?

Comment: No,  Daniel im using startActivity to start the BooksWithCategories activity which ive defined seperately. The class named CategoryButtonOnClickListener is used to handle clicks on a gridview which is populated with buttons. Im trying to get the text on the button through this listener, and subsequently open another activity (which will be a listview based on the text(CATEGORY) of the button. I hope this makes sense

Comment: There is no need for this extra class, and the problem is that you have it extending Activity.  Move all of the button click listener code to your BooksWithCategories Activity.

Comment: Also , i had to extend my listener class with the Activity class to call the startActivity function. I think im passing the wrong context object. But im not sure where im going wrong.

Comment: Im trying to open the BooksWithCategoriesActivity through this listener Im sorry i don't understand how can i call the activity from within itself..

Comment: Which Activity has the button?

Comment: The button is in an activity called Categories whcih displays buttons in a gridview , the listener sees which button is pressed and i need to populate a listview through an adapter according to the button pressed(the category of the button).

Comment: Hi Daniel, 
I was able to solve the problem from a post i found , I had the passed the context of the activity i wanted to start my activity from to the onClickListener, but i didn't call passedContext.startActivity(), and since i had extended my class with activity , it was throwing a nullpointer exception(due to this) Atleast thats where i presume the problem was being caused. Is this the apt solution?.. Im still a little unsure.

Comment: Sounds like it's still wrong.  It sounds like you should have the button click listener in the adapter for your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Place this method in your code :

```
 Activity getAct() {
    Context context = getContext();
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity) context;
        }
        context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then use it for starting the activity:

```
  Intent categoriesList = new  Intent(getAct(),BooksWithCategories.class);
```

Comment: Hmm, while this may work, it would seem that it would put the OP further down the path of a very strange and very wrong architecture.  There should be no need to use this code in an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

can try this

```
 Intent categoriesList = new  Intent(CategoryButtonOnClickListener.this,BooksWithCategories.class);
```

Comment: However the exception changes to
01-18 09:57:56.057    1967-1967/com.dogra.booker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dogra.booker, PID: 1967
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference